# Clarification on authorization/payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm having a bit of an issue understanding the different approaches between creating an authorization and capturing it and creating a sale and executing it.

When I create an authorization, the state is approved, as mentioned in the docs. I am able to use data from the response to later execute a capture. The response for the capture puts the payment state as 'completed'.

When creating a sale, via credit card info, the response is 'approved', which is conflicts with two different docs. One doc states that payment endpoint will mark the transaction as 'created', which can then be executed. However, my payment creation requests are marking the payment as 'approved' immediately, causing issues with the payment/pay-id/execute request, saying my transaction is in an invalid state.

My question is, what is the correct approach, if my payment with the intent of sale is immediately set as 'approved', does any further action need to be taken? What cases would mark the sale intent as 'created' before it is approved?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I'm an idiot. Purchasing via CC will immediately complete the purchase, since the credit card data was supplied with the request, validity of the payment method was able to be made. When the payment method is via paypal, you must firstly create the api request, which immediately creates the transaction with the state 'created'. it is 'approved' once the user validates purchase via pp, which can then be 'executed'.